# Why does a program need 64MB to install but frees up 3.5 MB when it is removed later in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, gnome-terminal, software-uninstall

Okay, I installed a 64MB sized program. Now I'm trying to uninstall it using Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge <program-name>
```

after running that command, the confirmation message will be:

```
blah blah blah...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  <program-name>*

After this operation, 3,577 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Now my question is what the hell is happening here?!

**64MB** on installation, then **3.5MB** after uninstalling???!

Comment: Was the program 64MB in size or was the total space used 64MB (including dependencies)? Do `apt-cache show <package-name> | grep -i size`.

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove orphaned packages which were installed as dependency with your program and no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ubuntu does not work like Windows**

In Windows, a program comes with pretty much all the files it needs.

In Ubuntu, a program uses a lot of common files. These are called dependencies. These common files are downloaded once and used by all the programs that need them. (This is one of the reason why Ubuntu does not install all the files in a single folder. It keeps different types of files in a common folder for that type of files so other programs can find them there.)

You may have installed some other programs that depend on some of these common files the first program installed as a part of the 64MB download.

When you remove the program, it looks at which other program will continue to need these common files and keeps them in place.

Sometimes this does not work too well, and some orphaned common files are left behind. You can use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to remove those files.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A package can depend on other packages. These are all installed when you install the main package.`sudo apt-get remove ...` does not automatically free the now-orphaned dependencies that were installed for your package.

A simple `sudo apt-get autoremove` should free up the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you uninstalled only main program, not other programs which were installed together with your main one, because he is using them.

You need to use `apt-get` together with `autoremove` command but...
**Be extra careful!**

A few weeks ago, I wanted to uninstall Python2.7 (I had newer version). I did `sudo apt-get autoremove python2.7`. Didn't know what exactly I'm doing, so wrote "yes". And saw, that something is wrong, when i get information "removing terminal". I removed half of my Ubuntu system, had to reinstall it.

So, **be extra careful** with autoremove command. I think, just don't use it, unless you **really** need more free space or you **really** know what are you doing. You will not lose too much by **not** using autoremove, just a little disk space, Ubuntu will not be slower. I will not use it anymore unless I will be sure I know what I'm doing.